# PHP and SQL insert statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So far I have created the table and getting a successful message. However when I go to insert into the table, I get: Error inserting sample record into 'Users': Column count doesn't match value count at row 1.

This is the code for creating the table:

```
mysql_select_db($dbName, $dbConnection);
$sql = "CREATE TABLE ".$dbTable." (ID int(6) auto_increment NOT NULL, Username varchar(20) NOT NULL, Password varchar(20) NOT NULL, UserType int(1) NOT NULL, FirstName varchar(15) NOT NULL, LastName varchar(15) NOT NULL, DOB DATETIME NOT NULL, Phone varchar(15) NOT NULL, Department varchar(15),PRIMARY KEY(ID))";
if(mysql_query($sql, $dbConnection))
{
    echo("Table '".$dbTable."' created<br />");
}
else
{
    echo("Error creating table '".$dbTable."': ".mysql_error()."<br />");
}
```

And this is the code for inserting:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ".$dbTable." (Username, Password, UserType, FirstName, LastName, DOB, Department) VALUES (1, 'admin', 'admin', 1, 'Admin', 'Admin', '1900-01-01', '12345656', 'IT')";
if(mysql_query($sql, $dbConnection))
{
    echo("Added sample record to '".$dbTable."' table<br />");
}
else
{
    echo("Error inserting sample record into '".$dbTable."': ".mysql_error()."<br />");
}
```

Comment: You have 7 INSERTs and 9 VALUES - Plus, if the first value is for your AI, remove it.

Comment: This is very dated. :-(

Comment: @user3502333 If you would have googled the exact error message with site:stackoverflow.com behind it, you would have found several duplicates... https://www.google.com/?q=Column%20count%20doesn%27t%20match%20value%20count%20site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: Go on with mysql functions. I hope you are going to find right way when you will become a victim of sql injection

Answer (score 1):

This line is the problem:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ".$dbTable." (Username,  //1
                                 Password,   //2
                                 UserType,  //3
                                 FirstName, //4
                                 LastName,  //5
                                 DOB,       //6
                                 Department) //7
        VALUES (1,             //1
                'admin',       //2
                'admin', //3
                 1, //4
                 'Admin',//5 
                 'Admin',   //6
                 '1900-01-01', //7
                 '12345656',  //8 You dont have column for this
                  'IT')"; //9  You dont have column for this
```

ie, the number of columns and the values are not matching. You have 7 columns and 9 values. So yuo need to add 2 more column names. Also do remember that you dont need to provide the value for auto incremented columns

The correct query may be like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ".$dbTable." (Username, Password, UserType, FirstName, LastName, DOB, Phone, Department) 
        VALUES ('admin', 'admin', 1, 'Admin', 'Admin', '1900-01-01', '12345656', 'IT')";
```

Note I have deleted ID as that is auto incremented

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to addthe phone number column. The count of your insert values should match the count of the columns you specify in your insert query.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to insert 9 values into 7 columns. In your insert statement, you've left out your `Phone` and `PRIMARY KEY(ID)` columns

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your INSERT statement...

Try this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ".$dbTable." (Username, Password, UserType, FirstName, LastName, DOB, Phone , Department) VALUES ('admin', 'admin', 1, 'Admin', 'Admin', '1900-01-01', '12345656', 'IT')";
```

As error itself says, *You are not providing me exact number of values as many you have specified the columns*

In short.

```
('col1', 'col2') VALUES ('val','val2')
```

Both **MUST** be same number of columns

In you case, You forgot to add the column name of the value `12345656`

Answer (score 0):

You do not add the id in `values..` and one phone is missing in the columns

```
INSERT INTO ".$dbTable." (Username, Password, UserType, FirstName, LastName,  DOB, phone, Department) VALUES ('admin', 'admin', 1, 'Admin', 'Admin', '1900-01-01', '12345656', 'IT')";
```